# how to exclude www from dynamically created subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

In my Laravel Application after User registration , I Assign a subdomain to each user based on her username.

If a User want to access a illegal and unregistered subdomain , I show 404 error page.

for that this is my Routes :

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.url')], function () {
     //some Other Routes for all Members
});


// Match a subdomain of my domain
Route::group(['domain' => '{username}.' . Config::get('app.url')], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@home']);
    Route::get('/news/{news_alias}', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@news_details']);
});
```

and in **config/app.php**, I have url option like this:

```
'url'             => 'tc.dev'
```

All things works fine But my Problem is when user try to open **www.tc.dev** domain , laravel shows **404 error page** because laravel thinks that as a username and could not found it and show error page.

How can I exclude **www** from subdomains so that act as a normal domain.

Comment: "dynamically created subdomain" - Presumably this is a _wildcard_ subdomain, or do you literally dynamically create it in DNS?

Comment: you can redirects it using .htaccess

Comment: @w3d, that is wildcard subdomain.

Comment: Although if a user does access `www.user.example.com` then that _should_ really result in a 404, or would it be preferable to redirect to `user.example.com`? What is `www.tc.dev` - is that your main domain? Is your main domain simply `example.com` (ie. no `www` subdomain)?

Comment: yes, if user wnat to access to `www.user.example.com` is better redirect to `user.example.com`. `www.tc.dev` is my main domain that must be considered as `tc.dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Laravel, but I think this would do the trick.

```
$routerFunction = function() {
    //some Other Routes for all Members
};

Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.url')], $routerFunction);
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.' . Config::get('app.url')], $routerFunction);


// Match a subdomain of my domain
Route::group(['domain' => '{username}.' . Config::get('app.url')], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@home']);
    Route::get('/news/{news_alias}', ['uses' => 'DashboardController@news_details']);
});
```

Comment: yes, that works fine really. this is simplest correct answer.